# Window's Snap Assist does not find my electron application

Tags: javascript, windows, electron

I am trying to figure out how to get Windows to [Snap Assist](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4027324/windows-snap-your-windows) my electron window (display thumbnails of open windows after snapping another window to one side).

For some reason, when I snap another program to half the screen, when it gives the option to select an app for the other half of the screen, my app is not available in the options.

Is there a feature or BrowserWindow configuration that needs to be turned on/set for this to work?

EDIT: I wanted to note that I know this can work, as it works in other apps like Slack and Discord.

EDIT: Adding the settings for my main browser window:

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    title: app.getName(),
    width: wndSettings.size.width,
    height: wndSettings.size.height,
    resizable: wndSettings.resizable,
    frame: false,
    icon: windowIcon,
    alwaysOnTop: false,
    show: false,
    autoHideMenuBar: true
});

mainWindow.on('ready-to-show', function () {
    mainWindow.show();
});
```

Resizable is initially set to false during a login screen, but becomes true once logged in.

Comment: Is your `BrowserWindow` resizable? Movable? Frameless?

Comment: Works fine for me, could you post your `BrowserWindows` settings?

Comment: I have added the settings for the browser window as requested.

Comment: Are you trying to snap your electron window at the beginning when it's unresizable, because then it won't be able to snap.

Comment: Also, can you Aero Snap your electron window using <Windows + arrow_key>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snap Assist will only display windows that are resizable. If your window is initially not resizable, then you won't be able to snap it to one side.

Update: I see now that this happens if you set `resizable` to false, and then make it resizable later via `setResizable(true)`.

This issue is being tracked [here](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/11568).

Comment: Thanks for linking the issue on github.

Answer (score 2):

I know that this thread is fairly old. Although, had the same issue just recently. For me removing `transparent : true` when creating the BrowserWindow object fixed it.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Was going bonkers with this problem.